# Create columns dynamically in pandas with keyword extraction

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
1,"this is a text","more text"
2,"this is another text","even more"
3,"here is one more", "something also here"
4,"let's get another one","we are close"
5,"one last text","finally"
```

Then I apply a Name Entity Recognition on those texts were I extract some of the important keywords. Like this

```
def get_entities(ocr, title):
    doc = nlp(' '.join([ocr, title]))
    entities = []
    for ent in doc.ents:
        entity = '_'.join([ent.label_, ent.text])
        entities.append(entity)
    return set(entities)

df['entities'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_entities( row.Col2, row.Col3), axis = 1)
```

The above creates a new column named `entities` that has as row values a list of different keywords. Let's say it is like that

```
Col1,Col3
1,['key1', 'key2']
2,['key3', 'key2']
3,['key4', 'key1']
4,['key3', 'key4']
5,['key5', 'key2']
```

Now what I try is to apply a `get_dummies` on that column and create all the possible keywords with row values `0-1`. The above would be

```
Col1,Col3,key1,key2,key3,key4,key5
1,['key1', 'key2'],1,1,0,0,0
2,['key3', 'key2'],0,1,1,0,0
3,['key4', 'key1'],1,0,0,1,0
4,['key3', 'key4'],0,0,1,1,0
5,['key5', 'key2'],0,1,0,0,1
```

Of course, applying the `get_dummies` directly on the list column doesn't work

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['entities'], prefix='entities')],axis=1)
```

I would appreciate any idea

Comment: Your function returns `set`, but in the description and sample output you say they are `list`s. Please clarify they are lists or sets, and update your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is changing what your function returns.  `get_dummies` can handle delimiter separated strings, which is trivial to return from your `get_entities` method.

---

```
def get_entities(ocr, title):
    ...
    return ','.join(set(entities))
```

Now you can use `get_dummies` directly on the result.  Using your second sample frame as an example, you would get:

```
df['Col3'].str.get_dummies(',')
```

```
   key1  key2  key3  key4  key5
0     1     1     0     0     0
1     0     1     1     0     0
2     1     0     0     1     0
3     0     0     1     1     0
4     0     1     0     0     1
```

---

If you *don't* want to change the return of the function, add another step before trying `get_dummies` using `str.join`

---

```
df['Col3'].str.join(',').str.get_dummies(',')
```

```
   key1  key2  key3  key4  key5
0     1     1     0     0     0
1     0     1     1     0     0
2     1     0     0     1     0
3     0     0     1     1     0
4     0     1     0     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `explode`, `str.get_dummies` and `join`

```
df.join(df.Col3.explode().str.get_dummies().max(level=0))

Out[206]:
   Col1          Col3  key1  key2  key3  key4  key5
0     1  [key1, key2]     1     1     0     0     0
1     2  [key3, key2]     0     1     1     0     0
2     3  [key4, key1]     1     0     0     1     0
3     4  [key3, key4]     0     0     1     1     0
4     5  [key5, key2]     0     1     0     0     1
```

---

If `df.Col3` is series of `set`, you need `agg` or `str.join` before `get_dummies` and `join` back to `df`

```
df.join(df.Col3.agg('|'.join).str.get_dummies())

Out[224]:
   Col1          Col3  key1  key2  key3  key4  key5
0     1  {key1, key2}     1     1     0     0     0
1     2  {key2, key3}     0     1     1     0     0
2     3  {key1, key4}     1     0     0     1     0
3     4  {key4, key3}     0     0     1     1     0
4     5  {key5, key2}     0     1     0     0     1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, his function returns a `set`, and you cannot explode a `set`.  You would need to `apply(list)` first which would be very slow.

Comment: @user3483203: oh, I base my answer on the sample table of columns `Col1`, `Col3` of list of `key1`,  `key2`. Hmmm... I need to take look the question again.